# Music player process

Tags: operating-system, processor

I was reading a book which says that a processor with single core and no hyper-threading can process  only one process at a time, so a doubt arises that when we do so many operations on a PC and also some background processes are always there then why not music player stops in between for short while. I know the CPU is pretty fast but still music player usually plays music in continuance without any small break ( that is observable ). Can anyone clarify this behavior?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1) A single-core CPU without hyperthreading can, as you say, only run one process at a time. Multiple processes are handled by context-switching, that is the CPU will run one process and then switch to the next process and the next and then back to the first process and so on. The frequency of how often a certain process is scheduled is dependent on lots of different factors, where process priority is one. (Back in the days it was often needed to run WinAmp with elevated priority to avoid glitches etc. Nowadays this is not needed as the CPU is a lot faster).

2) *So, with this in mind, how come it still sounds great and without glitches?*

When processing audio the CPU feeds the sound device with samples by putting them either in a hardware buffer on the sound card or in the RAM. The sound processor does not get its data directly from the CPU, instead it reads the samples from one of these two buffers. As long as we have samples in the buffer we are good, even though the CPU is off doing something else.

The details about the hardware buffer size is different on different sound cards. Some (older) sound cards does not have a sound buffer at all, and here the RAM comes into play instead.

Running out of samples is called *buffer underrun*. Even on modern computers this can happen, for example if you start a heavy process while running your audio player the CPU may not be able to switch back in time and we can clearly hear glitches and gaps in the sound feed.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to an operating system which does [preemptive multi-tasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29). The process is in fact being interrupted for a very short amount of time, not long enough to notice for a human. Another reason is also that the audio card has a playback buffer which allows the playback continously, while data is being fed to it in chunks. *So while the process of feeding the card with data is being interrupted for a very short time, the playback can still occur*.

Comment: but usually we don't hear any break. Is it that fast that we can't observe any break?

Answer (score -1):

This is handled by the Operating System Scheduler.

The scheduler will allocate a time slice to each process (this maybe a few milliseconds) and will allow a process to execute what it needs to for that length of time.  The length allocated is determined by the algorithm used by the OS (I.e. Short term scheduling, long term etc). The reason why you do not notice this is because the CPU can operate at such high frquencies, i.e. 1GHz which makes multi tasking on a single core / thread transparent to the user.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)
http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs3013/c07/lectures/Section05-Scheduling.pdf